# JLIRC is not working on Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, lirc

In JLIRC package is test class called `Irw` (Basicly clone of the original `irw` program from lirc). And on RPi 2B it produces that error http://pastebin.com/YY2cUSZb . The source of class is here: http://pastebin.com/mGBbQ4Zq . What could possibly go wrong?

EDIT: lircd IS running.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded JLIRC and installed it on my Raspberry 2 Model B.  Once 'make' ran (I found you have to change -march=i386 to armv7-a in the makefile for jni to compile), I did a make test and it ran with no problem.  Is that what you tried?  I have the latest Java SE installed.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try that, I compiled that on my PC :D